# Format cell alternating automatically by given value

Tags: excel, format, cell, formula

I can do this by giving a formula en every value (image 1), but I need to do only with one formula (image 2) alternating every two given values because there will be more tan 100 rows that it would do the same , may be I need a helper column...

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: You could use MOD arithmetic for cycles or IF/ELSE clauses for categorical conditions? Your formula may become quite complex, but I think it should work for what you're looking at.

Comment: I am assuming you want different formatting rules for alternating rows. If yes, you would need two rules. In each rule you would add one more condition to check if row is odd or even.

Comment: I found this woriking [=MOD(SUM(1/COUNTIF($C$4:$C4,$C$4:$C4)),2)=1] only with the first, third, fifth... group of data but I need the second, third, etc. data, well not really needed it could be blank

Comment: Solved for the second range: [=MOD(SUM(1/COUNTIF($C$4:$C4,$C$4:$C4)),2)<1]

Answer (score 0):

The format formulas that solved my problem are:

```
=MOD(SUM(1/COUNTIF($C$4:$C4,$C$4:$C4)),2)=1

=MOD(SUM(1/COUNTIF($C$4:$C4,$C$4:$C4)),2)<1
```